# How can I disable power menu from long press click on power button in android development?

Tags: android, kotlin, reproducible-research, operations-research

I've finished trying with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER in onKeyDown override method, execut Root command, dismiss system dialog and abortBroadcast() to prevent power-off or restart from power button's long press click event. But these're not working due to security reasons for android version>9.

Do you think we can use some kind of script to get that on android os?

I hope you're gonna give any idea to try. Thanks..

Comment: Can you imagine if Android actually allowed apps to hijack the power button like that?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't think android allows hijacking but I think there might be a way if the device user permission is allowed. In case a thief stole my phone and he/she can shutdown my phone easily that stop my background running process even my phone is locked. Do you have any idea to prevent that kind of issue rather than to disable power trigger in the settings? Thanks..

Comment: Not that I know of. Ability to turn the phone off is a critical feature that no app can stop.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same in Android 9 had the possibility to capture the long press power button but I think the only option and watching now it's make a custom os and modify the code